# multirow cell with a table (with 2 or more rows) inside

Tags: tables, multirow

When I have a long text inside a cell, I create a new table on that cell and break the text in many lines. The other columns will automatically aligned. But, when I have a multirow, the others columns get mixed. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llrrr}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Sexo} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{\hskip 0pt}l} Você concorda que o \\ Brasil não deveria \\ ter aceitado \\ realizar a copa? \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{Estado} \\ \cline{3-5} 
 &  & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{PR} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{RS} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{SC} \\ \hline 
\multirow{5}{*}{Feminino} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Concordo} & 40 & 32 & 51 \\  
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Concordo fortemente} & 33 & 35 & 30 \\  
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Discordo} & 29 & 35 & 28 \\  
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Discordo fortemente} & 42 & 34 & 35 \\  
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}{@{\hskip 0pt}l} Não concordo nem \\ discordo \end{tabular}} & 25 & 30 & 23 \\ \cline{1-5} 
\multirow{5}{*}{Masculino} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Concordo} & 31 & 35 & 51 \\  
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Concordo fortemente} & 26 & 40 & 36 \\  
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Discordo} & 26 & 38 & 34 \\  
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Discordo fortemente} & 31 & 31 & 37 \\  
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}{@{\hskip 0pt}l} Não concordo nem \\ discordo \end{tabular}} & 30 & 25 & 27 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Creates this table:

[image: Bad table]

And I want something like this:

[image: Good table]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a solution for `\multirow`, but I use to say that any table using it can be immediately improved by removing it. `;-)`

Here's how I'd realize the table, choose one of the two forms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=2.0]}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Você concorda que o Brasil não deveria} \\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{ter aceitado realizar a copa?} \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Estado} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}
& {PR} & {RS} & {SC} \\
\midrule
\bfseries Feminino \\
Concordo                  & 40 & 32 & 51 \\  
Concordo fortemente       & 33 & 35 & 30 \\  
Discordo                  & 29 & 35 & 28 \\  
Discordo fortemente       & 42 & 34 & 35 \\  
Não concordo nem discordo & 25 & 30 & 23 \\
\midrule
\bfseries Masculino \\
Concordo                  & 31 & 35 & 51 \\  
Concordo fortemente       & 26 & 40 & 36 \\  
Discordo                  & 26 & 38 & 34 \\  
Discordo fortemente       & 31 & 31 & 37 \\  
Não concordo nem discordo & 30 & 25 & 27 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=2.0]}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Você concorda que o Brasil não deveria} \\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{ter aceitado realizar a copa?} \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Estado} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}
& {PR} & {RS} & {SC} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Feminino} \\
\addlinespace
Concordo                  & 40 & 32 & 51 \\  
Concordo fortemente       & 33 & 35 & 30 \\  
Discordo                  & 29 & 35 & 28 \\  
Discordo fortemente       & 42 & 34 & 35 \\  
Não concordo nem discordo & 25 & 30 & 23 \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Masculino} \\
\addlinespace
Concordo                  & 31 & 35 & 51 \\  
Concordo fortemente       & 26 & 40 & 36 \\  
Discordo                  & 26 & 38 & 34 \\  
Discordo fortemente       & 31 & 31 & 37 \\  
Não concordo nem discordo & 30 & 25 & 27 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good example of table *re-organisation*.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions using the `makecell` package and its `makecell` & `\multirowcell` commands, the second using also `booktabs`, without vertical lines, that looks better in the opinion of most — the code is also simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll|rrr}
\hline
\multirowcell{4}{Sexo} & \multirowcell{4}{Você concorda que o \\ Brasil não deveria \\ ter aceitado \\ realizar a copa?}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Estado}} \\
 & & & &\\
 \cline{3-5}
 & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{2} {PR}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{2} {RS}} & \multirowcell{2} {SC} \\
  & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
 \hline
\multirowcell{6}{Feminino} & Concordo & 40 & 32 & 51 \\
 & Concordo fortemente & 33 & 35 & 30 \\
 & Discordo & 29 & 35 & 28 \\
 & Discordo fortemente & 42 & 34 & 35 \\
 & \makecell{Não concordo nem \\ discordo } & 25 & 30 & 23 \\
 \cline{1-5}
\multirowcell{6} {Masculino} & Concordo & 31 & 35 & 51 \\
 & Concordo fortemente & 26 & 40 & 36 \\
 & Discordo & 26 & 38 & 34 \\
 & Discordo fortemente & 31 & 31 & 37 \\
 & \makecell{Não concordo nem \\ discordo} & 30 & 25 & 27 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\clearpage

\begin{tabular}{ll rrr}
\toprule
\multirowcell{4}{Sexo} & \multirowcell{4}{Você concorda que o \\ Brasil não deveria \\ ter aceitado \\ realizar a copa?}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Estado}} \\
 & & & &\\
 \cmidrule{3-5}
 & & \multirowcell{2} {PR} & \multirowcell{2} {RS} & \multirowcell{2} {SC} \\
  & & & & \\
 \midrule
\multirowcell{6}{Feminino} & Concordo & 40 & 32 & 51 \\
 & Concordo fortemente & 33 & 35 & 30 \\
 & Discordo & 29 & 35 & 28 \\
 & Discordo fortemente & 42 & 34 & 35 \\
 & \makecell{Não concordo nem \\ discordo } & 25 & 30 & 23 \\
 \midrule
\multirowcell{6}{Masculino} & Concordo & 31 & 35 & 51 \\
 & Concordo fortemente & 26 & 40 & 36 \\
 & Discordo & 26 & 38 & 34 \\
 & Discordo fortemente & 31 & 31 & 37 \\
 & \makecell{Não concordo nem \\ discordo} & 30 & 25 & 27 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the multirow package the number a row actually means number of text lines which folowos in cels after multirow cell. This means, that in given mwe  the first multirow cell should have 4 for number of rows (see correction below). This seem to me as bug in multirow package ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llrrr}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Sexo} 
    &   \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{\hskip 0pt}l} 
        Você concorda que o \\ 
        Brasil não deveria  \\ 
        ter aceitado        \\ 
        realizar a copa? 
                        \end{tabular}} 
        &   \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}                                   \\
    &   &   \multicolumn{3}{|c}{Estado}                             \\
    &   &   \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}                                   \\
\cline{3-5}
    &   &   \multicolumn{1}{|c}{PR}
            &   \multicolumn{1}{|c}{RS}
                &   \multicolumn{1}{|c}{SC}                         \\
\hline
    \multirow{6}{*}{Feminino} 
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Concordo}               & 40 & 32 & 51  \\
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Concordo fortemente}    & 33 & 35 & 30  \\
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Discordo}               & 29 & 35 & 28  \\
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Discordo fortemente}    & 42 & 34 & 35  \\
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}{@{\hskip 0pt}l} 
        Não concordo \\ 
        nem discordo 
                            \end{tabular}}          & 25 & 30 & 23         \\ 
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Masculino} 
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Concordo}               & 31 & 35 & 51  \\
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Concordo fortemente}    & 26 & 40 & 36  \\
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Discordo}               & 26 & 38 & 34  \\
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Discordo fortemente}    & 31 & 31 & 37  \\
    &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}{@{\hskip 0pt}l} 
        Não concordo \\ 
        nem  discordo       \end{tabular}}          & 30 & 25& 27   \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Edit:
[image]